# GWT and Authentication

Tags: java, security, gwt

What are the best strategies to secure your GWT + Tomcat app to perform authentication and authorization?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Therea are two basic strategies:

1. secure the entry points;
2. secure the remote services.

## Secure the entry points

The simplest way is to restrict access to the html/js files generated by GWT using regular web application security tools:

- Spring Security;
- web.xml constraints.

This can allow you to have an e.g. `AdminEntryPoint` and `UserEntryPoint`.

## Secure the remote services

If the above solution is not enough, you can dig deeper. I have done so with Spring Security. I have not found a 100% clean way of integrating Spring Security with GWT, so I added a bit of glue. Briefly:

- created an annotation `@AllowedRoles` which enumerates the user roles allowed to access that service method;
- created a `UserDetailsService` which allows inspection of the current user ( see [the SecurityContextHolder javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) for details);
- created a Spring aspect which matches all methods annotated with the beforementioned annotation. It uses the service to retrieve the roles of the current user and throws a checked exception to signal an illegal access;
- modified all service methods to throw the security exception.

Comment: Robert, could you please give sample code of the mentioned aspect? (it's where I've stucked)